# Process exited with error(s) while compiling PdfLatex

Tags: errors

I got an error while compiling pdflatex, it shows,
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file qagb.pfb.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file f
or reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Please anyone help me to solve this error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That's an error in a map file (the double extension .pfb.pfb). It has been reported three days ago for texlive and corrected but seems to be still in miktex. I will make a bug report if it isn't gone after the next update round.

Comment: See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/37